# How to handle a Boolean when expecting a String in GSON?

Tags: java, json, rest, api, gson

I am currently developing with a 3rd party REST API. I am creating objects for their JSON objects being returned by the API. I am following their documentation where it says certain variables will be Strings. Sometimes when there is no String, it will return False. Sometimes I'm expecting a URL and I get False.

How do I handle this?

This is the API in question https://developers.cannabisreports.com/docs/

Strain Object EXAMPLE: https://ghostbin.com/paste/kgeau
In the Strain Object, I get an exception when performing a search. Some of the results of the search have booleans instead of strings/url in the bits of code that are commented out.

Sometimes I get this

```
"genetics": {
            "names": false,
            "ucpc": false,
            "link": false
        }
```

Sometimes I could get this

```
"genetics": {
            "names": "Blueberry x Haze",
            "ucpc": "W74AFGH22Z000000000000000 x 9XVU7WJQCD000000000000000",
            "link": "https:\/\/www.cannabisreports.com\/api\/v1.0\/strains\/9XVU7PTG2P000000000000000\/genetics"
        }
```

Comment: please post a working example / code

Comment: `getAsJsonPrimitive` then check if `isBoolean` or `isString` on the `JsonPrimitive` you got. I can add an example if you show some code.

Comment: I've updated with an example @Lino

Comment: Example! @AxelH

Comment: Its 500 lines of code @AxelH I will repaste it to a few other paste sites, because I cannot indent 500 lines in stack overflow very easily. https://pastebin.com/raw/2h356Eaz
or perhaps http://pasted.co/2ea74bc8

Comment: [mcve] ! See [ask]. You don't need 500 lines to recover one field from a `JsonElement`, at most you need 10lines.... What you are pasting is probably the full project.

Comment: Sir, what I am pasting is 1 JSON object, recreated in Java, and it is what you would need to replicate my issue in an IDE. The entire project contains multiple classes. My work around has been to exclude these objects that contain the unknown String or Boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in trouble with not a very well designed API, Gson gives you some flexibility while deserializing JSON documents produced by such an API. Despite you have *numerous* ways to work around this issue (like `JsonDeserializer`, etc), you mostly like are faced with the *false-as-null* issue I seem to have seen here already. You can help Gson by marking "wrong" fields:

```java
final class Envelope {

    final Genetics genetics = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("genetics", genetics)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

```java
final class Genetics {

    @JsonAdapter(FalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final String names = null;

    @JsonAdapter(FalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final String ucpc = null;

    @JsonAdapter(FalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final URL link = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("names", names)
                .add("ucpc", ucpc)
                .add("link", link)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

And this is how the type adapter factory implemented:

```java
final class FalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // No worries, Gson will instantiate it itself
    private FalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = gson.getAdapter(typeToken);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                    throws IOException {
                delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                // If the next token is a boolean
                if ( in.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN ) {
                    // and it's true
                    if ( in.nextBoolean() ) {
                        // then just report an unexpected `true` literal
                        throw new MalformedJsonException("Expected a null value indicator as `false`. " + in);
                    }
                    // and it's false, then we assume it's a null
                    return null;
                }
                // Otherwise read the whole value as a usual
                return delegateAdapter.read(in);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Once you deserialize the JSON documents you provided in the question, a `toString`-ed mapping might produce something like this:

```
Envelope{genetics=Genetics{names=null, ucpc=null, link=null}}  
Envelope{genetics=Genetics{names=Blueberry x Haze, ucpc=W74AFGH22Z000000000000000 x 9XVU7WJQCD000000000000000, link=https://www.cannabisreports.com/api/v1.0/strains/9XVU7PTG2P000000000000000/genetics}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know you will have a `boolean` or a `String`, you can get a [`JsonPrimitive`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html) directly.

> A primitive value is either a String, a Java primitive, or a Java primitive wrapper type.

Then from the `JsonPrimitive` instance, you can check if it [`isBoolean`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html#isBoolean--).

Here is how to use it in a small snippet

```
public static String getURL(JsonObject json, String value){
    JsonPrimitive data = json.get(value).getAsJsonPrimitive();
    if(data.isBoolean()){
        return "Boolean : " + data.getAsBoolean();
    } else {
        return "String : " + data.getAsString();
    }
}
```

And here is a quick example to validate this logic

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = 
            "{"
            + "    \"element\" : {"
            + "        \"a\":false,"
            + "        \"b\":\"foobar\""
            + "    }"
            + "}";
    JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(data).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject element = json.get("element").getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(getURL(element, "a"));
    System.out.println(getURL(element, "b"));
}
```

> Boolean : false
>   String : foobar

---

The json used :

```
{
    "element" :{
        "a":false,
        "b":"foobar"
    }
}
```