# Deserialize json with boolean or object field

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I use `Retrofit` and `GSON` and I'm getting Json like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "passporRf": {
        "number": "996633",
        "series": "1111",        
        "code": "66666"
    }

}
```

And when user doenst have a passport - this fields is boolean with "false" value.

How to deserialize it correctly and get boolean value - false, when this field is boolean and get JSON object when its object.
I found a `JSONDeserializer` but i cant to use it correctly. Code is:

```
public class DocumentDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Passport> {


    @Override
    public Passport deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonPrimitive primitive = json.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if (primitive.isBoolean()) {
            // What value do i have to return here?
        }
        return context.deserialize(json, Passport.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your current attempt.

Comment: try to change this behavior. This makes no sense

Comment: i cant change backend - so i have to work with this all my life

Comment: @pligosv you'll need to show us what you've tried to do with your `JSONDeserializer`. You say you 'can't use it correctly' - please clarify what you mean by this. Edit your original question to include some more details about what you've tried and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Often I think GSON is more trouble than it is worth. This would be so easy using `JSONObject`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns updated question

Comment: maybe i can try to parse Documents object and when i got Exception - return null for this field?

Comment: Never use an `Exception` as normal pathway for your code. An `Exception` should be an exception!  Did Sachin Varma suggestion not work?

Comment: I am a little lost here. Without any custom deserializer, you can get the populated object or a null value for the ```passportRf``` object when the field is passed with ```false``` value. A simple verification of ```if (passportRf == null) {...}``` would then solve your problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: Almost **exact** duplicate of [How to handle a Boolean when expecting a String in GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097025/how-to-handle-a-boolean-when-expecting-a-string-in-gson)

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv :: It really is a bit hard to see what the OP is dealing with, but my interpretation is that the key `passporRf` is returned either as it is shown above OR like this `"passporRf":"false"`...so he has an either or JSON structure.

Comment: @Barns I do believe the OP is confused with the `false` serving a `null` literal, and I'm almost sure this is why the OP put the _// What value do i have to return here?_ comment.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv :: All speculation I would say considering the OP also wrote "when this field is boolean and get JSON object when its object" ...So either boolean or object.  In any case, it appears the OP has abandoned this question. He hasn't once responded to any of the "answers"

Comment: @Barns Not an issue: Gson can deal with almost all odd APIs just requiring a special custom type adapter telling Gson how to deal with this or that. This would cover your interpretation as well, because you can have multiple options here: `java.lang.Object` (not sure if Gson permits (de)serialization here), `com.google.gson.JsonElement`, or a custom `PassportOrBoolean` (but why `false` anyway? what about `true`? -- I'm still for the "`false` ~ `null`" idea). But yes, let's see what the OP would respond.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv :: I'll take your word on that! But, I can solve this issue with 5 lines of parsing code--no need to for a custom adapter--no need for a third party library.  For most of my JSON parsing requirements I come out fine using the Android built-in JSONObject library. I almost never use third part libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use GSon nor any other binding library. Nothing can be bound to "either a boolean or an object", so don't try.

Use a JSON parser, and look at the JSON content to obtain the information you want. Possibly build a User object out of the information you can find.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv The approach proposed in that answer is 100% effective, saves time, and produces better quality code. The better quality code is made particularly obvious with the other proposed solution. Care to justify how is it wrong?

Comment: Gson can do what the OP is asking for, and I believe, so does Jackson and any other (de)serialization library that supports (de)serialization strategies configuration.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Of course they can. I never said they can't, so how is the answer wrong? I said that impossible bindings can't be done, so it is preferable to not try. Indeed it is possible to still use Gson and other binding libraries, at the price of jumping through hoops to circumvent their binding functionality and make them use a customized extractor instead of binding. It is possible, but how is it in any way useful, helpful, nor in any way a good idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, my English skills are far from being perfect, but doesn't your last comment contradict with your answer? I can define a super type for both of these types (`java.lang.Object`, `com.google.gson.JsonElement`, `foo.bar.FooBar`), and implement a custom (de)serializer, because it's worth of making a poorly designed API more convenient to use. This idea is good idea and sane, especially if a binding library  is designed to support configuration for even very odd APIs.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv No, my answer tells to not try a bad idea. Not that this bad idea won't ever work. I don't, however, understand your theory that using a poorly designed API may be worth it, at least when using a well-designed one is a trivial option.

Answer (score 0):

Code is given below,

Sample.class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Class containing news information in form of POJO.
 */
public class Sample {


  public String firstName;


  public String lastName;


  private List<SampleOne> passporRf;

  public List<SampleOne> getPassporRf() {
    return passporRf;
  }

  private void setPassporRf(List<SampleOne> passporRf) {
    this.passporRf = passporRf;
  }

  // Using custom DeSerializer for "multimedia" object since the API is just "Great"
  public static class SampleDetailsDeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<Sample> {

    @Override
    public Sample deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      Sample accountState = new Gson().fromJson(json, Sample.class);
      JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

      if (jsonObject.has("passporRf")) {
        JsonElement elem = jsonObject.get("passporRf");
        if (elem != null && !elem.isJsonNull()) {
          if(elem.isJsonPrimitive()){
            accountState.setPassporRf(null);
          } else {
            final List<SampleOne> passporRfList = new Gson().fromJson(elem.getAsJsonArray().toString()
              , new TypeToken<List<SampleOne>>(){}.getType());
            accountState.setPassporRf(passporRfList);
          }
        }
      }
      return accountState ;
    }
  }

}
```

SampleOne.class

```
public class SampleOne {
  public String number;
  public String series;
  public String code;
}
```

Hope it may help you.